# Error: An immer producer returned a new value *and* modified its draft. Either return a new value *or* modify the draft

Tags: reactjs, redux, immer.js, redux-toolkit

I have my reducer

```
const userAuthSlice = createSlice({
    name: "userAuth",
    initialState: {
        token: '',
    },
    reducers: {
        setToken: (state, action) => state.token = action.payload.test,
    },
});
```

And I have my dispatch command

```
<button
   value={text.sign_in.submit}
   onClick={() => dispatch(userAuthSlice.actions.setToken({test:"test"}))}

/>
```

As I press the button what I get is this error:

[image]

I have isolated everything to be sure that this is the problem and nothing else.

Why does this error pop up?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The issue is the use of an arrow function with no curly braces as the reducer, because that acts as an implicit return statement.  So, you're both mutating `state.token`, *and* returning the result of the assignment.

Per [the Immer docs on returning data](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/return#inline-shortcuts-using-void), there's a couple ways to fix this:

- Adding the `void` operator in front of the assignment
- Wrapping the assignment in curly braces to make it a function body

---

so `setToken` reducer can be updated with `void` as

```
setToken: (state, action) => void(state.token = action.payload.test)
```

Answer (score 13):

Points to learn about `IMMER`

1. If you return anything other than draft from the recipe function, that return value will replace the state
2. You mostly want to mutate the draft to mutate the state, ** so returning draft after modifying it is optional**, the `immer` will return finalized draft anyway
3. if you return anything else from `recipe` function then as per point 1, the new return value will replace the state
4. **Point 3 is ok, only if you do not modify the draft in your recipe function**. i.e. you can choose one of the two

   a. modify the draft --> return draft or undefined, either is ok
   b. want to return some new value, then don't touch the draft at all

---

Now coming to answer for the question.
this is your reducer function

```
(state, action) => state.token = action.payload.test
```

This function is doing two things, 
1. modifying state 
2. returning action.payload.test
so it's violating point 4 and hence the error from Immer library

in this specific case, intention is only to modify the state, so we have to undo the existing return with `void`

```
setToken: (state, action) => void(state.token = action.payload.test)
```

However, Immer library recommends the use of code block to insure consistency across large code-base, this code block implicitly returns undefined

```
setToken: (state, action) => { state.token = action.payload.test }
```

Answer (score 11):

Correct answer

> Use Instead of

```
const userAuthSlice = createSlice({
    name: "userAuth",
    initialState: {
        token: '',
    },
    reducers: {
        setToken: (state, action) => state.token = action.payload.test,
    },
});
```

> Use this {I have just added brackets}

```
const userAuthSlice = createSlice({
    name: "userAuth",
    initialState: {
        token: '',
    },
    reducers: {
        setToken: (state, action) => { state.token = action.payload.test}, // <<= Change Here
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who are working with [React PullState](https://github.com/lostpebble/pullstate), my issue was with the syntax:

I had:

```
 const onUpdate = (value: any) => {
    someStore.update((s) => (s.value = value));
 };
```

but has to be:

```
 const onUpdate = (value: any) => {
    someStore.update((s) => {
       s.value = value;
    });
 };
```

Check that I sorrounded the declarations with brackers `{}`

For some reason, doesn't like the arrow function declared on the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 state.token = action.payload.token
```

use

```
 const token = action.payload.token
 state.token = token
```

Constants are immutable, and assigning action.payload contents to a constant resolved a problem for me (Note that in case the payload is an object it is not necessary

Working example of createSlice:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'login',
  initialState: {
      username: "Foo",
      password: "AAA",
      authorized : false
  },
  reducers: {
    setUsername: (state, action) => {

      const value = action.payload
      state.username = value // action.payload.username

    },
    setPassword: (state, action) => {

      const value = action.payload
      state.password = value // action.payload.password

    },
    logon: (state, action) => {

      state.username = action.payload.username
      state.password = action.payload.password
      state.authorized = true

    },
    logoff: state => state.authorized = false
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove return statement only and .test

Answer (score -4):

you may forget break; statement at your reducer.js file;

```
 case LOGIN_USER_ERROR_RESET:
        draft.errormsg = '';
        draft.loading = false;
        draft.error = false;
        break;
```