# Can't make filter work with Immer.js to remove nested object in array

Tags: javascript, immutability, immer.js

I'm starting with Immer.js for immutability in JS and I **can't find a way to remove an object in an array using the filter method**. It returns the same object. BTW, I'm doing it in React with state but to make it more straightforward I made up simple snippets that reflect my problem.

```
const sampleArr = [
      {
        items: [
          { slug: "prod1", qnty: 1 },
          { slug: "prod2", qnty: 3 },
          { slug: "prod3", qnty: 2 },
        ],
      },
    ];
    
    const newState = produce(sampleArr, (draft) => {
      draft[0].items.filter((item) => item.slug !== "prod1");
    });
    
    console.log(newState);
```

Console.log was supposed to give me the same whole array but without the first item. However, what **I get is the same array without any change**.

I googled it and searched on immer docs but couldn't find my answer. Immer.js docs about Array mutation => https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/update-patterns

Obs. To test it out on chrome dev tools you can copy-paste the immer lib (https://unpkg.com/immer@6.0.3/dist/immer.umd.production.min.js) and change produce method to immer.produce

Answer (score 2):

Using destructuring for making immutable objects goes against Immert.
The way of solving this issue is by reassigning the filtered part to draft.
The solution looks like this:

```
const sampleArr = [
  {
    items: [
      { slug: "prod1", qnty: 1 },
      { slug: "prod2", qnty: 3 },
      { slug: "prod3", qnty: 2 },
    ],
  },
];

const newState = produce(sampleArr, (draft) => {
  draft[0].items = draft[0].items.filter((item) => item.slug !== "prod1");
});
```

You can play around in the repleit here:
https://replit.com/@GaborOttlik/stackoverflow-immer#index.js

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up solving the problem on my own even though I'm not sure it's the right way.

What happens is that I need 2 things:

1. A return from the produce function
2. Copy the rest of the properties and add them to the new return

That said, if we write like this:

```
const newState = produce(sampleArr, (draft) => {
    return draft[0].items.filter((item) => item.slug !== "prod1");
});
```

We get back the filtered items array

```
[
    { slug: "prod2", qnty: 3 },
    { slug: "prod3", qnty: 2 },
]
```

However, it's required to add back the rest of the properties. Suppose you have more data, etc. So I did like this:

```
const newState = produce(sampleArr, (draft) => {
    draft = [
        ...draft.slice(0,0),
        {
            ...draft[0],
            draft[0].items.filter((item) => item.slug !== "prod1"),
        }
        ...draft.slice(1)
    ];
    return draft;
});
```

EDIT =================================================

Found out it's not required to do all that I did above. I could've done the way I did first. Was just lacking an assignment.

`draft[0].items = draft[0].items.filter((item) => item.slug !== "prod1");`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into is that Immer doesn't allow you to both modify a draft and return a completely new value from the produce. Doing so will produce the following error discussed in further detail under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60806105/error-an-immer-producer-returned-a-new-value-and-modified-its-draft-either-r):

> Error: An immer producer returned a new value *and* modified its draft. Either return a new value *or* modify the draft

As pure speculation I would guess this is intentionally disallowed because this would almost always be a bug, except for this specific use-case.

To sidestep the problem, what you can do is wrap the array you want to work with in a temporary object and then destruct that object as you retrieve the result:

```
const { newArray } = produce({ newArray: oldArray }, (draft) => {
  // Filtering works as expected
  draft.newArray = draft.newArray.filter(...);

  // Modifying works as expected
  if (draft.newArray.length) {
    draft.newArray[0].nested.field = ...;
  }

  // No return statement
});
```